# how to convert datetime format to date in c# in web services?

Tags: .net, web-services

```
  student_info siInfo = new student_info();

  siInfo.Dob = Convert.ToString(dataReg.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Dob"]);
```

how to show date from datetime..

Comment: Seriously? ToShortDateString() did not show up in IntelliSense for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

siInfo.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReg.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Dob"]).ToShortDateString();